# REACT router cannot access params when using render()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-props

I am new to redux, I created a route to navigate to user edit page and i also want to pass store and history as props using the code below.

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" render={({history}) => (
          <EditUser store={store} history={history} />
)}/>
```

But now i cannot access the params which i am passing (:id) in my EditUser component. When i try to access using **this.props.match.params.id**, it shows undefined, but it works if i rewrite my route to

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditUser}/>
```

But now i think case i am not able to pass other props.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: which `<Route>` are you using `<BrowserRouter> `, share your index.js?

Comment: yes i am using <BrowserRouter> in my index.js

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `match` you have to pass it to your component.

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" render={({history, match}) => (
  <EditUser store={store} history={history} match={match} />
)}/>
```

You could also just pass all the props:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" render={props => (
  <EditUser store={store} {...props} />
)}/>
```

Or you can use react-redux's `connect` function to get access to the store

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component={connect(mapStateToProps)(EditUser)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome answer with multiple ways of wiring react-router with react-redux. I can't believe this isn't more obvious in the docs...